# in power Query: How to create conditional column that removes numbers and keeps text

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

col 1 contains rows that have just numbers and just text. example:

```
row 1 = 70
row 2 = RS
row 3= abcddkss
row 5 = 5
row 6 = 88
```

and so on
What I want to do is add a column using logic like this: if Col1 not a number then Col1 else null.

what I have so far:

```
=let mylist=List.RemoveItems(List.Transform({1..126}, each Character.FromNumber(_)),{"0".."9"})
in

if List.Contains(mylist,Text.From([Column1])) then [Column1] else null
```

however, this will not work for rows that have more than one letter and will only work on ones that have one letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if Value.Is(Value.FromText([dat]), type number) then null else [dat]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also check if the string is purely digit characters.

```
if [Column1] = Text.Select([Column1], {"0".."9"}) then null else [Column1]
```